# What am I missing in "Decision to Leave"?

Tags: plot-explanation, decision-to-leave

In *Decision to Leave*, the detective, Park Hae-il discovers that Grandma's phone has zero steps a day except for the day of the possible murder (138 steps) of Seo Rae's husband, he then back-tracks Seo Rae's steps to discover if it was possible she committed the murder.

He leaves Grandma's house, gets on a bus, gets off the bus and walks to the base of the rock, climbs the rock, at the top of the rock he checks his step count; it's 138 steps and deduces that Seo Rae murdered her husband.

How is this possible?

1. Grandma's phone records the total step count for that day; so 138 steps is for the return journey to the top of the rock, not the one-way trip. So step count at the top of the rock should have been 69 steps.
2. Even if the bus stop is right outside Grandma's house, Even if she sits at the front of the bus, Even if the bus stops right at the base of the rock.
   She still has to climb the rock (From the images I guesstimate this to be 100-150m high, the actual height could have been mentioned earlier in the film)
   She still has to run across the top of the rock to gain sufficient momentum to push her husband off the rock,
   She then has to retrace her steps back to Grandma's house to swap the phones back.

How is this only 138 steps?

The margin of error on this is too much to be 'believable' so have I missed something?

Comment: I don't think there's a need to warn about spoilers in the title *and* at the top of the post, ***and*** hide the entire post in spoiler tags as well. One or the other will suffice.

Comment: I thought the count was not *steps* done walking, but flights climbed. I can't recall the translated wording but that was how I interpreted it.

Comment: @matt_black, can you please define "flights"? I assume you mean flight as in a 'flight of stairs'? How many steps in a flight? Does descending a flight count the same as ascending a flight?

Comment: @7caifyi "Flights climbed" is the exact term an iPhone uses to work out whether you have climbed *up* a certain distance. It measures in "floors" not steps and it does not count going *down*.

Comment: @matt_black, that makes more sense.